# Delete account option missing after changing the profile page recently

Tags: support

I would like to delete the account on Stack Overflow? I have not found any option there after changing the profile page design.
How do I delete the account on Stack Overflow?

Comment: None of the related posts shown on the right side is useful for you?

Comment: that suggesting how to delete the post, answer etc.. I want to remove my entire account? What I mean after doing that my account imaphpdeveloper should not be displayed anywhere

Comment: after chaging the profile page, the option is not there?

Comment: This got nothing to do with the redesign. Account with activity could never be deleted via button click, even in the old design.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the bottom of the page and click [**contact us**](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Next to "What can we help you with?" select "I need to delete my user profile".

Follow the steps from there.